# How can I print double letters from string in a list without using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I would like to know how to find the appearance of double letters in a list of strings without using regular expressions. Below is what I have so far.

```
word="kookss"
new_words=["laal","mkki"]

def double_letter(word):
       for i in range(len(word)-1):
            if word[i]== word[i+1]:
                return (word[i],word[i+1])
 print(double_letter(word))
 for w in range(len(new_words)-1):
      print(double_letter(new_words))

output :
 ["OO","ss"]
 ["aa"]
 ["kk"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
word="kookss"
new_words=["laal","mkki"]

def double_letter(word):
    # each double letter found should be put in this list.
    double_letters = []
    for i in range(len(word)-1):
        if word[i]== word[i+1]:
            double_letters.append(word[i] + word[i+1])
    return double_letters

print(double_letter(word))

for w in new_words:
    # for each word `w` in list `new_words` call double_letter method
    print(double_letter(w))
```

output:

```
['oo', 'ss']
['aa']
['kk']
```

your code is not working because:

```
for w in range(len(new_words)-1):
      print(double_letter(new_words))
```

This code you are passing `new_words` (which is a list) to `double_letter` method which is expecting a single word.
Suddenly `word[i]== word[i+1]` becomes `"laal" == "mkki"` which is false so your return is `None`

you pass the same list twice so you get 2 `None`.